# Connect to remote instance of Elasticsearch through spring data elasticsearch using an URL

Tags: java, elasticsearch, https, connection

I'm very newbie to ES and I'm having a lot of troubles to connect to an external instance od ES through my java web app, let's say that I have the following client config

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.elasticsearchlogs.elasticsearchlogsbackend"})
public class Config extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Value("${elasticsearch.url}")
    public String elasticsearchUrl;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        final ClientConfiguration config = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo(elasticsearchUrl)
                .build();
        return RestClients.create(config).rest();
    }
}
```

When I was making some tests with `elastichsearchUrl = "localhost:9200"` all was fine, but know i should connect to an ES instance that is in a  external server, that is accesible, let suppose by the following url `https://elasticinstance.com` (yes it uses Https).

The problem is that if a put the url like in the example, java complains because it asks for a port number. I don't really know what port number have I to give it, I have tried with 9300 and 9200 because they are the default ports in ES, also with 443 because is the default port in Https.

What should I do? Shall I ask my admin to give me a port number to connect? Or shall I configure the client in any special way?

Answer (score 0):

I think as you are trying to connect to external Elasticsearch server with Https, first

1. Go through, https://www.elastic.co/blog/configuring-ssl-tls-and-https-to-secure-elasticsearch-kibana-beats-and-logstash, this tells you how to Create SSL certificates and enable TLS for Elasticsearch.
2. Then you can try and access Elasticsearch with https://[ip/domainname:port].com

Or to validate first if everything is OK with current setup

3. Just access the server only with HTTP instead of HTTPS.